# Laravel sync/attach tags

Tags: php, laravel, tags

I am working on tag functionality on Laravel and continue by this great tutorial: https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-fundamentals/episodes/22?autoplay=true

But i have problem with sync/attach functionality.
When i try attach is it only updated post_tag table, not the tag table.
Then all post is pointed to non existing tag with id 0.

Saving seems like:

```
...
if ($request->get('tags')) {
    $tagsarr = array_slice(array_unique($request->get('tags')), 0, (int)siteSettings('tagsLimit'));
    $post->tags()->attach($tagsarr);
}
    $post->save();

    return $post;
```

When I *dd($tagsarr);* i have:

```
array:3 [▼
  0 => "tag1"
  1 => "tag2"
  2 => "tag3"
]
```

After helping i change code to this:

```
...
$post->save();

    if ($request->get('tags')) {
        $tagsarr = array_slice(array_unique($request->get('tags')), 0, (int)siteSettings('tagsLimit'));
        $tagIds[] = Tag::firstOrCreate($tagsarr)->id;

        $post->tags()->attach($tagIds);
    }

    return $post;
```

**The solution:**

```
$post->save();

    if ($request->get('tags')) {
        $tagsarr = array_slice(array_unique($request->get('tags')), 0, (int)siteSettings('tagsLimit'));

        foreach($tagsarr as $tagitem) {
            $tagIds[] = Tag::firstOrCreate(['tag' => $tagitem])->id;
        }

        $post->tags()->attach($tagIds);
    }

    return $post;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`attach()` shouldn't do anything with `tags` table. If you're creating new post you should save object first:

```
$post->save();
```

And only then use `attach()`.

Also, `$tagsarr` should contain IDs of tags, but not tag names.

Comment: This cannot help me. Still same results. Without _$post->save();_ too.

Comment: Fix `$tagsarr`. It should contain IDs of tags, like `[1, 4, 12]`. And put `dd($post);` right before `$post->tags()->attach($tagsarr);` and show me result please.

Comment: Tags doesn't exists already - need to create it. But i am surprised, that tags cannot be created with attach or sync.

Comment: So, you should create these first. Also you should have (create or get) post and only then use `attach()`.

Comment: Hmm, but me problem is it how create new one when not exists in table? Can i create it for table tags with id, tagname? Really hard for me find solution for this now.

Comment: You should save tags into the `tags` table and save their's IDs. Like `$tagIds[] = Tag::create($newTagData)->id;`

Comment: Actually this isn't solution, because the tag with this name can exist in table already and then i need only tag id, not create new one. Is available sync function or something like that?

Comment: There is `firstOrCreate()` method.

Comment: Sorry i saw it after. Me mistake. But still error with database. I will update the code in my post. The error is: _SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '0' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `tags` where (`0` = tag1 and `1` = tag2 and `2` = tag3) limit 1)_ Thank you for helping, you help me a lot really.

Comment: That's not how [`firstOrCreate()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#other-creation-methods) works. You should find/create tags one by one by passing array with model values to `firstOrCreate()`.

Comment: I thought there is some function for that. I am now thinking how it can be done...